# "analytic on $\mathbb{R^2}$" vs. "analytic on $\mathbb{C}$"

Tags: complex-analysis

My course notes (Mathematics BSc, third-year module in complex analysis, unpublished) have,

> **Definition:** A real-valued function $u(x,y)$ on a region $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ which has continuous second order partial derivatives and satisfies Laplace's equation on $D$ is said to be *harmonic* on $D$.

> **Theorem:** If $f=u+iv$ is analytic on a region $D$, then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic on $D$.

> **Examples:** In each of the following cases decide whether there is a function $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ such that Re$(f)=u$.

There seems to have been a slip from "$f$ analytic on $\mathbb{R^2}$" to "$f$ analytic on $\mathbb{C}$". Is the difference unimportant?

Comment: @AlvinL [region means open and connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(mathematical_analysis))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that analyticity of a function $f : \mathbb C \mapsto \mathbb C$ is not the same as analyticity of the corresponding function $F : \mathbb R^2 \mapsto \mathbb C$, where $f$ and $F$ are related by $f(x+iy)=F(x,y)$ (and similarly when the domain of $f$ is an open $D \subset \mathbb C$ with corresponding open domain $D' = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x+iy \in D\}$ for $F$). Here I'm using the common definition of analyticity: $f$ is analytic (i.e. complex-analytic) if it is equal to its power series in the single complex variable $z=x+iy$; whereas $F$ is analytic (i.e. real-analytic) if it is equal to its power series in the pair of real variables $x,y$.

Nonetheless, this kind of abuse of language is quite common in complex analysis. In fact, in a discussion of complex analysis, real-analyticity is generally ignored. The very theorem that you cited can in some sense be taken as a justification for this abuse of language: if $f$ is analytic on $D$ then each of the two coordinate functions of $f$, **thought of as 2-real-variable functions** (i.e. as the two coordinate functions of $F$), are harmonic on $D'$. There's also a converse to this theorem: if the two coordinate functions $u,v$ of $F$ are harmonic, and if those two functions are related in a certain manner (e.g. the integral relation written down [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicConjugateFunction.html)), then $f$ is analytic.

Comment: Good idea, I'll fix that.

Comment: @PierreCarre Love of God I had a heart attack from the $f'$ notation XD

Comment: Heh. So much for geometric group theorists answering complex analysis questions.

Comment: Lee Mosher...the integral relation is simply that they are harmonic conjugates or something? Or what?

Comment: Lee Mosher can you give an example where $f$ is analytic while $F$ isn't or vice-versa? I guess this is about hmmm...complex-analytic vs real-analytic or something?

Comment: @BCLC: I think it's a good idea to bring the terminology "complex-analytic" vs. "real-analytic" into the discussion; I added them to my answer.

Comment: @BCLC: And yes, that integral relation is equivalent to being harmonic conjugate. I wanted to avoid the terminology of "harmonic-conjugate" because, in the present discussion which is taking place down at the very roots of things, it would have led in a circle: the very definition of the statement "$u,v$ are harmonic conjugate" is that $u+iv$ is complex-analytic.

Comment: @BCLC $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $F(x+iy) = x$ is real-analytic but not complex-analytic.  Real analytic means "is equal to a convergent power series in $x$ and $y$ in a neighborhood of each point".  Complex analytic means "is equal to a convergent power series in $z$ in a neighborhood of each point".

This is a generalization of real/complex linearity and real/complex differentiability.

Comment: ah ok thanks i missed the $z$ vs $x,y$ thing. oh yeah i remember now.

Answer (score 2):

A complex function $f = u + i v$ is analytic if and only if it is differentiable. This is quite different from what happens in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where a function is analytic if it has derivatives of all orders and is representable as a power series.

Comment: Did you mean *A complex function* where you wrote *O complex function*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Corrected!

Comment: @mjc I must correct part of my answer/comments. In fact, using Cauchy's integral formula it is not hard to show that if $f = u + i v$ is analytic at a given point, then $u$ and $v$ have continuous derivatives of all orders at that point.

Comment: Would you now agree with the theorem as written, or would you say there are complex-analytic functions whose real part doesn't satisfy Laplace?

Comment: @mjc I agree with the theorem as it is written.